# Dependency injection net core console application setup

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, console-application

I am trying to use dependency injection for a .Net Core Console application using the built in DI.

I have 2 following Methods :

```
    private static void RegisterServices()
    {
        var collection = new ServiceCollection();

        //repositories
        collection.AddScoped<IAccountDataRepository, AccountDataRepository>();
        collection.AddScoped<IClientDataRepository, ClientDataRepository>();
        collection.AddScoped<IAddressDataRepository, AddressDataRepository>();
        collection.AddScoped<IClientAccountDataRepository, ClientAccountDataRepository>();
        //services
        collection.AddScoped<IAccountDataService, AccountDataService>();
        collection.AddScoped<IClientDataService, ClientDataService>();
        collection.AddScoped<IAddressDataService, AddressDataService>();
        collection.AddScoped<IClientAccountDataService, ClientAccountDataService>();

        _serviceProvider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();

    }

    private static void DisposeServices()
    {
        if (_serviceProvider == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (_serviceProvider is IDisposable)
        {
            ((IDisposable)_serviceProvider).Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I can get this to work in the main method by using this:

```
private static IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
private static IClientDataRepository _clientDataRepository;



static void Main(string[] args)
{

    RegisterServices();

    _clientDataRepository = _serviceProvider.GetService<IClientDataRepository>();
```

However I need to inject the repository to the service and the service to main but I can t use the following in the service class :

```
_clientDataRepository = _serviceProvider.GetService<IClientDataRepository>();
```

Here is service:

```
public class ClientDataService : IClientDataService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IClientDataRepository _clientDataRepository;

    public ClientDataService(ILogger logger, IClientDataRepository clientDataRepository)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _clientDataRepository = clientDataRepository;
    }
```

If I use

```
_clientDataRepository = _serviceProvider.GetService<IClientDataRepository>();
```

will give an error

Comment: Just resolve the service and the service provider will inject the repository into the service when building the object graph of the requested object

Comment: "will give an error". Please provide us the details of that error. Please post the full stack trace, exception type, and message of the exception and *all* inner exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Just resolve the service and the service provider will inject the repository into the service when building the object graph of the requested object

Based on the provided `ClientDataService` you would also need to make sure that all dependencies are registered with the service collection.

As it is current shown, `ClientDataService` also depends on `ILogger` which does not appear to be registered with the service collection.

```
services.AddLogging();
```

The following example uses the originally provided code and refactors to run the main using dependency injection.

```
public class Program
    private readoonly IClientDataService service;

    public Program(IClientDataService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void SomeMethod() {
        //...
    }

    //entry
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = RegisterServices();

        Program program = serviceProvider.GetService<Program>();

        program.SomeMethod();

        DisposeServices(serviceProvider);
    }

    //Support
    private static IServiceProvider RegisterServices() {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        //repositories
        services.AddScoped<IAccountDataRepository, AccountDataRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IClientDataRepository, ClientDataRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IAddressDataRepository, AddressDataRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IClientAccountDataRepository, ClientAccountDataRepository>();
        //services
        services.AddScoped<IAccountDataService, AccountDataService>();
        services.AddScoped<IClientDataService, ClientDataService>();
        services.AddScoped<IAddressDataService, AddressDataService>();
        services.AddScoped<IClientAccountDataService, ClientAccountDataService>();
        services.AddLogging(); //<-- LOGGING
        //main
        services.AddScoped<Program>(); //<-- NOTE THIS

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    private static void DisposeServices(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        if (serviceProvider == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (serviceProvider is IDisposable sp) {
            sp.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```